# Set value of two elements with same css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using same css for a select dropdown and a input textbox. I set the values in jquery like this:

```
$('.a').val('2');
```

When checking the value of the select and input elements, they are correctly assigned but when I display their values via console.log, I get undefined for both. Why is that?

```
console.log($('.a').find('select').val());
console.log($('.a').find('input').val());
```

Result:

```
undefined
undefined
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/04oLs3he/12/

Comment: and why you added the `find` ? it makes a big difference. you need `select.a` and `input.a`

Comment: thanks but can't i use find? why doesn't it work?

Comment: You can't use `find()` as it won't be the right way to do that,  however you can use `.filter()` but it will be an overkill operation here, the easiest way is to use `select.a` and `input.a` as suggested by @TemaniAfif.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect (no need of `find`). Try following

```js
$('.a').val('2');

console.log($('select.a').val());
console.log($('input.a').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="a">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="a" value="Three">
```

Comment: `find` will search in the html of selector element i.e. in our case, it will try and return `input` and `select` elements which have a parent element with class `a`. However, as there will be no element returned, `.val()` will return `undefined`. Hence, to use `element` with `class` selector, you will need to follow the approach specified.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks.

Comment: @superigno - Glad to help you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.find()` to get the value, because it will search for children `input`/`select` elements inside your selected element.

And don't use the same `selector` to get both elements, use `$('input.a')` to get the `input` and `$('select.a')` to get the dropdown element:

```
console.log($('select.a').val());
console.log($('input.a').val());
```

**Note:**

If you want to change the `input` value when you change the option in the `select`, use the `change()` event to track this change.

**Demo:**

```js
$('select.a').change(function() {
  $('input.a').val($(this).val());
});

console.log($('select.a').val());
console.log($('input.a').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="a">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="a" value="Three">
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead. `find` will try to find **child elements** of the selected one unlike filter which will filter the selected elements:

```js
$('.a').val('2');

console.log($('.a').filter('select').val());
console.log($('.a').filter('input').val());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="a">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="a" value="Three">
```

Comment: We can use `.filter()` but it will be an overkill operation here to get all elements then filter them, the easiest way is to use `select.a` and `input.a` as you suggested in comments.

Comment: @chŝdk I know the easiest and that what I suggested in the comments ;) but he seems to insist on using find and in this case it's the filter function he want not the find

Comment: Yes in that case it can be used only as replacement for `.find()`. ;)